# Why does authority to deactivate the shield transfer from the Death Star II to the Executor?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

In the opening scene of [*Return of the Jedi*](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html), Darth Vader's shuttle drops from the hangar bay of his command ship *Executor*, and heads toward the Death Star under construction.  The shuttle commander makes contact with the Death Star to drop the shields:

> SHUTTLE CAPTAIN:
> Command station, this is ST 321. Code Clearance Blue. We're starting
> our approach. Deactivate the security shield.
>
> DEATH STAR CONTROLLER (filtered VO):
> The security deflector shield will be deactivated when we have
> confirmation of your code transmission. Stand by... You are clear to
> proceed.
>
> SHUTTLE CAPTAIN:
> We're starting our approach.

At this point in the film, the Death Star has the authority to raise or lower shields.  If the *Executor* also had such authority at this time, the above dialogue would not have been necessary.

---

Later in the film, Han Solo is commanding a stolen shuttle, and plans to land on the nearby moon.  Instead of approaching the Death Star itself, he flies near the *Executor*, which gives the command to lower the shields:

> VADER:
> Where is that shuttle going?
>
> PIETT  (into comlink):
> Shuttle Tydirium, what is your cargo and destination?
>
> PILOT VOICE    (HAN)   (filtered):
> Parts and technical crew for the forest moon.
>
> The Bridge Commander looks to Vader for a reaction.
>
> VADER:
> Do they have a code clearance?
>
> PIETT:
> It's an older code, sir, but it checks out. I was about to clear them.
>
> Vader looks upward, as he senses Luke's presence.
>
> PIETT:
> Shall I hold them?
>
> VADER:
> No. Leave them to me. I will deal with them myself.
>
> PIETT  (surprised):
> As you wish, my lord.
> (to controller)
> Carry on.

At this point in the film, the *Executor* now has the authority to raise or lower shields.

---

**Why is the authority to raise or lower the shields delegated to the *Executor*?**  Why not simply leave that authority up to the Death Star itself?

What makes even less sense is that the *Executor* can be moved away (and eventually does) from its station near the Death Star, making it a bad choice to control the shields.  The Death Star itself is always in place above the shield generator, so why not keep the control of the shields there?

Comment: A WAG:  The death star, still under construction, is not able to generate the shield at all times.  When construction/maintenance interrupts the DS's generator, the Executor takes over shield generation duties.

Comment: Thr shield was generated on Endor - the mission was to destroy it. I assume (with no evidence) that on first arriving Executor had to prove its credentials, but once Vader had taken over control his ship also had authority over all resources in the system  including control of the shield.

Comment: @SottoVoce that is not in any way what is happening

Comment: Its referred to as a "command ship", and given than the DSII is not supposed to be operational at the time of the attack, it makes sense that protection duties are controlled by one of the fleet detailed to protect it?  Also, why does the ships proximity to the DSII or the moon have any bearing on its ability to issue commands?  If it leaves the system, its duties can be delegated to another ship.

Comment: No explanation of the change was given in the original novelization.  However, the novelization hews vary close to the screenplay draft that was available to the adapter, James Kahn, with very, very little additional material added.